# Microsoft Access Query Return Issue

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have made an Access database to keep track of monthly payments for a soccer and basketball club. The database includes a `Clients` table and a `Payments` table.

Each payment record is linked to a specific client. Each month, payments are made by clients. I have created a query to return all of those who have **not** made their monthly payment.

For my query to return these clients who have not paid, I enter the month I am searching for and if they don't have a record that matches that then they will be included in the list.

I have run into an issue with the second payment month. For example, if I type in `"June"` as the month I'm searching for, people who have a record for `"May"` show up in the list, even if they've paid for `"June"` as well.

I have tried looking into different ways to filter the table but am not sure of how to filter it in such a way that these unwanted values will not show up, nor do I know if that's possible. I also realize that this issue could be done away with if I were to delete old data as I update the table monthly, but I would like to keep track of who is paying each month and not have to delete records. I have not added any additional code to try to mitigate this issue, as I'm unsure of what to do.

```
SELECT Clients.[Player ID], Clients.[Player Name], Clients.[Contact Number], Payment.[Payment Amount], Payment.[Payment Month]
FROM Clients INNER JOIN Payment ON Clients.[Player ID] = Payment. [Player ID]
WHERE (((Payment.[Payment Month]) Not Like [Enter the month:])) OR (((Payment.[Payment Month]) Is Null));
```

To reiterate, I'd like for someone's name to show up when I type in `"June"` if they have **not** paid for that particular month. I do not want their name to show up if they've paid for `"June"` but also `"May"` as the record for `"May"` shows up in the query results. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You must change your table schema to hold the _year_ and _month_ as _numbers_, not literals. Then you can easily filter whatever you need regarding (un)paid year/months.

Answer (score 2):

To obtain the appropriate results from your query, I would suggest using a subquery in conjunction with a `left join` in the following way:

```
select
    clients.[player id], 
    clients.[player name], 
    clients.[contact number]
from
    clients left join 
    (
        select payment.[player id] 
        from payment
        where payment.[payment month] = [Enter the month:]
    ) payments
    on clients.[player id] = payments.[player id]
where
    payments.[player id] is null
```

Alternatively, you can use a correlated subquery such as:

```
select
    clients.[player id], 
    clients.[player name], 
    clients.[contact number]
from
    clients
where not exists 
(
    select 1 from payment 
    where 
    clients.[player id] = payment.[player id] and 
    payment.[payment month] = [Enter the month:]
)
```

Here, I have used the equality operator (`=`) in place of the `like` operator given that I suspect you are unlikely to want to match multiple month names using wildcards.

However, as @Gustav correctly points out - both of these will include results from multiple years unless you also include a field to store the payment year alongside the payment month.

I would also suggest storing the month as an **integer value** (as opposed to a string) so that it may be indexed more efficiently; then, should you wish to display the month name in a query or as a parameter, either use a separate `Months` table, or use the [MonthName](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/monthname-function-c64bcf54-2534-45bc-acef-de80f4a959c4) function.

Alternatively, use a Date field to store the payment date, and then use the [Year](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/year-function-bbdfc30e-7234-43ec-ae59-9c6420ca5c54) & [Month](https://support.office.com/en-ie/article/month-function-78182042-7bf0-46e9-829e-c7012f773fc5) functions or a date range in your selection criteria.